# HtmlWindow doesn't display page in wxpython notebook layout

Tags: python, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

I have a project set up as a notebook layout using wxpython.  I am trying to create a help panel.  The HtmlWindow object doesn't display the html page on the panel.  No errors are displayed and a call to HtmlWindow.GetOpenedPage() returns the page name.

```
import wx
import wx.html as html

class HelpPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.help = html.HtmlWindow(self.panel, -1, style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.help.LoadFile('help.html')
        self.sizer.Add(self.help)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Show(True)

    def add_help_panel(self, parent, evt):
        self.help_panel = HelpPanel(parent, -1)
        parent.AddPage(self.help_panel, 'Help')
        parent.SetSelection(parent.GetPageCount()-1)
```

Here is the call from the menu to open the HelpPanel:

```
wx.EVT_MENU(self, ID_HELP, lambda evt: help.HelpPanel.add_help_panel(help.HelpPanel(self.nb, -1), self.nb, evt))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be how your adding your `HtmlWindow` object  to your sizer, try  and setting the EXPAND flag and the proportion to 1.

```
self.sizer.Add(self.help, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Doug: Consider adding a runnable sample of the problem to your question, it will make it easier for someone to diagnose your problem, otherwise its a guessing game.